# When inserting a link in Sitecore, how to make the Target to be "Active browser" by default?

Tags: sitecore-client

At the moment when inserting an internal link in Sitecore, by default the Target is set to "Custom". Is there a way to manually change this within the Core database?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the default value for the Target drop down list, but you can change the order of its options, so that the "Active browser" appears at the top of the list.

Follow the below simple steps to change the sort order of the **Target** list in the **Link Details** form:

1. Switch to the Core DB in the Sitecore Desktop;
2. In the Content Editor, navigate to the `/sitecore/client/Business Component Library/version 1/Templates/Common/Text` folder and add a new field of the `Single-Line Text` type to store the sort order. For example, call it `SortOrder`;
3. Navigate to the `/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog/PageSettings/Targets` folder and set the sort order value for each target individually using `1`, `2` and `3` values; make sure that `1` is set to the "Active browser" target option;
4. Navigate to the `/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog/PageSettings/TargetsSearchPanelConfig` item and set the value of the `Sorting` field to `aSortOrder` (should be "a" followed by the name of your Sort field from step 2).
5. Important to rebuild the `sitecore_core_index` index; go to the Control Panel > Index Manager and select the core index for rebuild.